# Command clears environment in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, glassfish

I am new to batch files, so please forgive me if I don't use the proper terminology here.

I have a batch file that needs to undeploy one specific application from all my listed Glassfish domains. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set glassfishDomains=domainA4841,domainB4842

for /d %%a in (%glassfishDomains%) do (
    set fullDomain=%%a
    set port=!fullDomain:~-4!
    set domain=!fullDomain:~0,-4!
    echo Undeploying appName on domain !domain! !port!
    asadmin --host localhost --port !port! undeploy appName
    echo.
)
```

The problem is that it is "losing the state" after the asadmin commands is executed for the first time.

```
asadmin --host localhost --port !port! undeploy app
```

Just for clarity, asadmin.bat is Glassfish's command line tool.

If I remove this line/command from the file, the loop performs the string extraction just fine, using delayed expansion. This is the resulting output in that case:

```
Undeploying app on domain domainA 4841

Undeploying app on domain domainB 4842
```

By "losing state" I mean that variables don't get the correct values anymore. After the first asadmin command execution, I start to get this result:

```
Undeploying appName on domain domainA 4841
Command undeploy executed successfully.

D:\>(
 set fullDomain=domainB4842
 set port=!fullDomain:~-4!
 set domain=!fullDomain:~0,-4!
 echo Undeploying appName on domain !domain! !port!
 asadmin --host localhost --port !port! undeploy appName
 echo.
)
domainB4842
Undeploying appName on domain !domain! !port!
CLI136: Port !port! should be a numeric value.
Command --host failed.
```

So the question is if there is a way to avoid "losing the script state" after these commands execute? Or is this some sort of limitation from that tool (asadmin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cmd /C "asadmin --host localhost --port !port! undeploy appName"
```