# Difference between call and cmd /c in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, call

Can someone please explain what's the difference between

```
call someBatchFile.bat ...
```

And

```
cmd /C someBatchFile.bat ...
```

They both were suggested to me as solutions to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39049641/2316433) problem, but I don't understand why they both work, and more importantly, if there are any significant differences I must be aware of.

Comment: Second statement starts a new process, any changes that someBatchFile.bat makes to environment variables won't affect and won't be visible to your current batch file.  Could be good, could be bad.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095847/why-is-there-no-need-for-call-to-return-from-called-batch-script-which-is-invo/36096956#36096956).

Comment: @Aacini that was the answer I was looking for. Since the linked question is different, I think it would be beneficial if you answered it here as well. Will you please do that so that I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is that `call` execute the other Batch file *in the same context* of the caller program, so they share the same environment variables and other status (like `echo ON/OFF` or delayed expansion), whereas `cmd /C` execute the other Batch file in an entirely separated context, so any change made in the called Batch file is *not* reflected in the original file.

Just as a personal note, I used to name *internal subroutine* the Batch file invoked via `call`, and *external subroutine* the one invoked via `cmd /C` (and *overlay* the Batch file directly invoked without `call` nor `cmd /C`, that *inherits* the behavior and context of the caller Batch file).